# "milling over the grass" meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Sirius stared around at the students **milling over the grass**, looking rather haughty and bored, but very handsomely so.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

I'm not sure what "**milling over the grass**" truly means. I've looked up the word ['mill'](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mill), but I don't know which one fits for the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Milling](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/milling)** is defined as:

> *moving around in a large group, with no particular purpose, or in no particular direction*

In this context, JKR must've intended to convey that the students were roaming around, probability with no particular intention; or rather to kill time.